# php performance check changes var

Tags: php, performance, variables

I have a    question about performance in php.

I have multiple variables of settings which I want to write in session. First I thought it would make sense to check it before if it need the change:

```
if($settings['search_rule'] != $searchRule)
{
    $_SESSION['search_rule'] = $searchRule;
}
```

But I am not sure if it would be better just write

```
$_SESSION['search_rule'] = $searchRule;
```

So I can skip the IF for less steps in code. I think not that it would make much difference but I want to improve my code.

For example if I have 10 settings and just one changes which one is faster?

Comment: Only use the `if` when you need to know a change is made (i.e. call another function or create a message saying it's been updated), just replacing the value is a lot clearer if that is all you are doing.

Comment: You can answer your own question: You current code says: If the value of `$settings['search_rule']` is **not equal** to `$searchRule`, then write it to the session, else do not modify it. Do you only want to modify the value if it has the specified value or is this just a "If not exists create else update" thing?

Comment: I just want change the vars. My thoughts are about the performance of writing in vars VS an IF. May the writing is slower if just one of 10 changes so an if would be faster in this example. In this code the target is to check if the values changes.

Answer (score 0):

if it is always will have a value, you can go with the second option.

`$_SESSION['search_rule'] = $searchRule;`